# setting up the number of cross validation in j48 tree weka

Tags: java, weka

I want to use weka j48 tree with 5-cross validation. Here is my code so far,

```
public class WekaJvMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try
         {  
             CSV2Arff converter =new CSV2Arff();
             converter.convert();

             DataSource source = new DataSource("data.arff");
             Instances train = source.getDataSet();

             train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);  // setting class attribute

             // classifier
             J48 j48 = new J48();
             j48.setUnpruned(true);        // using an unpruned J48

             j48.buildClassifier(train);
             System.out.print(j48.graph());

         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }      
    }
}
```

This code trains the data and prints out the j48 tree. However I could not find how to set up the number of folds for cross validation? Please explain in detail, I am not good at Java.

Comment: Do I understand correctly?  You want to evaluate J48 with 5 fold cross validation?

Comment: Yes, with 5 fold or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code augmented with a 5-fold cross validation evaluation of your j48 classifier.  It is important that you do the evaluation before training the final classifier.  Additional information can be found [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code#Classification-Cross-validation).

```
public class WekaJvMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try
         {  
             CSV2Arff converter =new CSV2Arff();
             converter.convert();

             DataSource source = new DataSource("data.arff");
             Instances train = source.getDataSet();

             train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);  // setting class attribute

             // classifier
             J48 j48 = new J48();
             j48.setUnpruned(true);        // using an unpruned J48

             //evaluate j48 with cross validation
             Evaluation eval=new Evaluation(train);

             //first supply the classifier
             //then the training data
             //number of folds
             //random seed
             eval.crossValidateModel(j48, train, 5, new Random(1));
             System.out.println("Percent correct: "+
                                Double.toString(eval.pctCorrect()));


             j48.buildClassifier(train);
             System.out.print(j48.graph());

         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }      
    }
}
```